# Преобразовать в список линию с графика

Tags: python, list

Строю график сглаживания данных, на выходе получается линия:

```
plt.plot(polyline, model(polyline))
```

Как ее преобразовать в один список `z`?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

x = [6, 9, 12, 12, 15, 21, 24, 24, 27, 30, 36, 39, 45, 48, 57, 60]
y = [12, 18, 30, 42, 48, 78, 90, 96, 96, 90, 84, 78, 66, 54, 36, 24]

model = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 2))
polyline = np.linspace(1, 60, 50)

# ? z = [polyline, model(polyline)] ?

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(polyline, model(polyline))
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: z = model(polyline) ?

Comment: почти, происходит смещение в лево, а этого быть не должно

Comment: А что должно быть??

Comment: так ничего не должно быть, на графике вон она как располажилась, а при z = model(polyline) тоже самое но смещается

Comment: Вы все ещё никак не хотите понять, что 2D графики строятся по точкам, каждая из которых имеет  __две__ координаты. Определитесь в каких точках по оси X вы хотите получить значения Z!

Comment: @ЛеонидВ Так у вас данные начинаются от `x=6`, а полином вы строите начиная `x=1` вот вам и смещение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятна задача, но попробую предположить, что вам нужен на выходе список координат формата `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`

Питоновский метод:

```
z = list(zip(polyline, model(polyline)))
# [(1.0, -23.186794966968563),
#  (2.204081632653061, -14.962603388967386),
#  (3.4081632653061225, -7.04863899144604),
```

Но поскольку это массивы `Numpy`, то лучше через `Numpy`:

```
z = np.column_stack((polyline, model(polyline)))
# array([[  1.        , -23.18679497],
#        [  2.20408163, -14.96260339],
#        [  3.40816327,  -7.04863899],
```

Comment: у вас происходит также как и для z = model(polyline) смещение графика полинома влево, только бонусом еще добавляется прямая линия регрессии

Answer (score 4):

Попытаюсь угадать и формализовать задачу по описанию из вопроса. Если я правильно угадал, автор вопроса хочет получить значения смоделированной функции в точках из массива `x`:

```
z = model(x)
```

графики:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(polyline, model(polyline))
plt.scatter(x, z)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прямо интересно - кто же лучший телепат? ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, представляете насколько скучным был бы вопрос если бы Леонид его нормально сформулировал - "Как найти значения функции в заданных при помощи списка точках?" ?? :-D